# Copying columns from two different files and write them to a new file

Tags: awk

I found many similar posts but they don't quite work for me. So I am posting this question.

I have a file test1.txt

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
a b c d e
```

and another file test2.txt

```
a b c d e f g
h i j k l m n
o p q r s t u
```

I want two take the 6th column from test2.txt and the last column from test1.txt and form a new file test3.txt:

```
f 5
m 0
t e
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: What did you try so far? Better if you post your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
paste test2.txt test1.txt | awk '{print $6, $NF}' >test3.txt
```

- Redirect output: `>test3.txt`
- `paste` merges the lines of the two files side by side
- The result is piped to `awk` which prints the sixth and last columns

`NF` (sans dollar sign) is an `awk` built-in variable which holds the *number of fields*. As fields are referenced by `$expr`, the last field can be referenced as `$NF`.

Comment: What does $NF signify?

Comment: @physu See update